# Matlab mle fitting vs Python Scipy

Tags: python, matlab, mle, scipy.stats

I'm converting a Matlab code into a Python version. The Matlab code uses the Maximum Likelihood Esistamtion `mle` function to fit to a set of samples a Rayleigh and Rice distribution.

It then uses the `pdf` function to compute the values of the pdf (given the estimated parameters) at some points.

The equivalents in Python are the `scipy.stast.rayleigh/rice.fit` functions. Problem is that for example the Rayleigh one in Python is the standardized version that return both a location and scale parameter whereas the Matlab `mle` returns only the scale parameter. Similar for the Rice case, Python version return 3 parameters whereas Matlab only two (as per definition of the Rice distribution).

I know that for the normal distribution location = mean and scale = variance so I was expeceting that for Rayleigh the scale in Mtalb is the same as the scale in Python but it seems they are used differently.
The problem obviously propagate when I use the parameters  in my code since I do not have a 1to1 match,

Is there a way to have in Python the same "behavior" as in Matlab?

Sorry for the silly question but the Scipy documentation, to my opinion, is not very complete.

Thank you

Comment: Any help, did some testing and I was not able to match the two "types" of parameters

Answer (score 0):

According to the Matlab documentation:

[image]

Compare against the SciPy documentation:

[image]

However, in SciPy, all probability distributions get `loc` and `scale` parameters:

[image]

Consequently, to get the same behavior in SciPy as in Matlab, set `loc = 0` and `scale = b`.

For example:
[image]

In SciPy:

```py
from scipy import stats
x = 1
b = 0.5
dist = stats.rayleigh(loc=0, scale=b)
dist.pdf(x)  # 0.5413411329464508
```

---

The story is similar for Rice. In Matlab:

[image]

SciPy:

[image]

So to get SciPy to agree with Matlab, set `loc=0`, `scale=sigma`, and `b = s/sigma`.

[image]

```py
x = 1
s = 1.5
sigma = 2
dist = stats.rice(b=s/sigma, loc=0, scale=sigma)
dist.pdf(x)  # 0.1724423399627125
```